# Vb NET: Adding CheckBox to TableRow

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm having a problem adding the checkbox to my header row in the grid view.

It throws out the error as:

> 'TableRow' cannot have children of type 'CheckBox'.

```vb
Dim HeaderGrid As GridView = DirectCast(sender, GridView)
Dim HeaderGridRow As New GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Insert)

Dim HeaderCell As New TableCell()
Dim CheckBox As New CheckBox()
HeaderCell.Text = ""
HeaderGridRow.Controls.Add(CheckBox)

HeaderCell = New TableCell()
HeaderCell.Text = "Service"
HeaderGridRow.Cells.Add(HeaderCell)
GridView1.Controls(0).Controls.AddAt(0, HeaderGridRow)
```

Comment: Add them to a cell, not a row.

Comment: @VDWWD value of type 'Checkbox' cannot be converted to 'TableCell'. Please assist.

Answer (score 0):

You are currently adding `CheckBox` to `HeaderGridRow`. You need to add it to `HeaderCell` instead:

```
HeaderCell.Controls.Add(CheckBox)
```